# How can I customize the FreeTextBox menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, freetextbox

I want to customize the menu of my FreeTextBox (FTB) control on an ASPX page. How do I add/remove elements from it? I'd also like to enable its spell checking feature. Any help/references will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others reference... You can set the FTB's ToolbarLayout property with a string of buttons used to create the toolbar. Use commas (,) to separate items. A pipe (|) will insert a separator

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="FTB1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="280px"
                    ToolbarLayout="ParagraphMenu, Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, CreateLink, Unlink, RemoveFormat, JustifyLeft, JustifyRight, JustifyCenter, JustifyFull, BulletedList, NumberedList, Indent, Outdent, Cut, Copy, Paste, Undo, Redo, ieSpellCheck">
</FTB:FreeTextBox>
```

Spell check is done via ieSpell which doesn't work with firefox. Currently looking at NetSpell for the Spell-check feature.